# Custom Record with Custom Sublist - access data?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is there a way to access a custom sublist on a custom record via suitescript? I have a record that users will enter criteria into that will then populate a bom in the sublists section via a saved search. Is there a way to access this data? When I try to run currentRecord.getSublists(), it says that it is not a function.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The currentRecord module indeed does not have getSublists(), but the record module does. Maybe you can load the record and then call getSublists() on the record object?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that would probably work. What I am trying to do is highlight the rows that meet some criteria. For whatever reason I cannot update my search (it errors out) to highlight, so I was going to try to do it programmatically, but I cannot seem to access the actual sublist. I'll keep trying and see if I can do it another way if I have to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case people still run into this issue, it's a matter of dynamic vs static records.

currentRecord in a User Event is both a static record and cannot be "saved" (i.e. if you want to make changes in an afterSubmit method).

You'll want to record.load in dynamic mode to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
var linect = rec.getLineItemCount('recmachcustrecord');
```